# Grails Events Push plugin not getting a response from server event

Tags: grails, push

I have been trying to get the grails events push plugin to work but cant seem to get response data from the server when the `savedToDo` event is called.  I can see the logs in my console for the data coming to the server and executing the service code, but the client doesnt seem to be getting back a response.  My code is as follows :

MyService.groovy

```
package eventspush

import grails.converters.JSON

import grails.events.*

class MyService {

   //will receive client events from 'saveTodo' topic
    @Listener(namespace='browser') 
    def saveTodo(Map data){
        log.info(data)
        data.moreData = "There we go...."
        event('savedTodo', data) // will trigger registered browsers on 'savedTodo' topic
    }
}
```

conf/MyEvents.groovy

```
events = {
    "savedTodo"  browser: true, browserFilter: { message, request ->    
     return true
  }
}
```

index.gsp

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head>
    <r:require modules="grailsEvents"/>
    <meta name='layout' content='main'/>
    <r:script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

      /*
       Register a grailsEvents handler for this window, constructor can take a root URL,
       a path to event-bus servlet and options. There are sensible defaults for each argument
       */
      window.grailsEvents = new grails.Events("${createLink(uri: '')}", {logLevel:"debug", transport:'websocket'});

        var data = new Object();

        data.name="some name"

        grailsEvents.send('saveTodo', data); //will send data to server topic 'saveTodo'
        grailsEvents.on('savedTodo', function (data) {
        console.log(data)
        }, {});


    });
    </r:script>
</head>
```

My problem is that I am not seeing any data being logged in the console.  Does anybody have any idea what I am doing wrong?

Edit, I have worked out what was wrong and I have updated the MyEvents.groovy accordingly, the above code is now working

Comment: The basic documentation [here](https://github.com/smaldini/grails-events-push) doesn't have a return type for the service method. Check if it works without the 'def' part.

Comment: The other thing that you might want to try is a hardcoded address for new Events(...) in the javascript.

Comment: what should the URI of the new Events(URI) be pointing to?

Comment: what's in your `MyEvents.groovy` file? please consider that this file must not import anything and it also must not include the `"$EventsPushHandler.GLOBAL_TOPIC"  browser:true` definition. just a simple file with the following content `events = { 'savedTodo' browser: true }`. a namespace is not required for this example to work ...

Comment: please see my edited answer - I found a little typo in your JS code ;)

Comment: I'm not sure that what you say is correct as the first event it to save the todo and the event to respond to the client browser is the saved event.  I'm thinking there is an issue using tomcat

Comment: @andymccullough ahhh - yes! there is an issue, sorry I didn't mind it earlier ... still have not thought about it! you have to declare `grails.tomcat.nio = true` within your `BuildConfig.groovy` file

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have added the 'savedTodo' mapping to the `PushEvents.groovy` file within the `Plugin` directory. *This is wrong!*

You should add your own `*Events.groovy` file within the `conf` folder of your own project and leave the `PushEvents.groovy` file of the plugin untouched!

<strike>The other code looks fine so far ;)</strike>

There's a typo within your JavaScript section in `index.gsp`:

it reads:

```
grailsEvents.send('saveTodo', data);
```

when it should be:

```
grailsEvents.send('savedTodo', data);
```

you omitted the "d" ... ;)

Comment: this isnt a typo, there is a save event -> object saved -> saved event, but thanks for the input, as you were correct about the events closure being in the wrong place.  thanks

Answer (score 0):

So I found out what what was causing the data not being pushed to the client.

I edited the line in `MyService.groovy` from being

`event('savedTodo', data)`

to

`event(topic:'savedTodo', data:data)`

It is now working as expected

Comment: glad you found the solution and shared it with us ;)

Comment: no problem, though would you have any idea on this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14981682/how-to-dynamically-create-a-new-a-topic-using-events-push-plugin