# How to use Events push plugin in grails

Tags: grails, notifications, push, grails-plugin, gsp

I tried the following set up for my project to send notification to UI using Events-push plugin http://grails.org/plugin/events-push

```
main.gsp
----------
<html>
  <head>
    <r:require modules="grailsEvents"/>
    <r:script>
        grailsEvents.on('myTestEvent', function (data) {
            alert ("Testing data recieved : "+data)
        }, {});
    </r:script>
   </head>
</html>


MyTestController.groovy
------------------------
def testMyEvent() {
 event for:'myApp' topic:'myTestEvent' data:"Testing something"
}


BuildConfig.groovy
------------------

plugins {
    build ':platform-core:1.0.RC5'
    build ':events-push:1.0.M7'
    compile ':platform-core:1.0.RC5'
    runtime ':platform-core:1.0.RC5'
    compile ':events-push:1.0.M7'
    runtime ':events-push:1.0.M7'
}

MyEvents.groovy (grails-app/conf)
---------------    
    events = {    
        'myTestEvent' namespace : 'myApp', browser:true, browserFilter: { message, request ->
            println "myTestEvent event raised"
            return true // allows browser push on this topic
        }
    }
```

Initially I faced problem as the events-push plugin not able to find atmosphere plugin. So I had to manually copy paste under the grails home (`<grails_home>/lib/jars/atmosphere-0.9.0RC3 and atmosphere-1.1.0-SNAPSHOT`). Then it started compiling the project. But the `<r:>` tags are not getting compiled and throws the runtime error as `Error executing tag <r:layoutResources>: No module found with name [grailsEvents]`
I am not able to find a proper documentation of how to make it work. Can some body point out a proper way of setting this plugin step by step and make it work?
I referred this [Grails Events Push plugin not getting a response from server event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14943049/grails-events-push-plugin-not-getting-a-response-from-server-event) but still I am not able to make it work. Any help is much appreciated!!!

Answer (score 2):

May be [this repository](https://github.com/manishbharti/events-push-sample) helps you.
Have a look..,.

Also read [this](https://github.com/smaldini/grails-events-push) documentation.

And you are getting unable to resolve dependency atmosphere plugin because you haven't mention

```
mavenRepo "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/"
```

in repositories block in build config.

Comment: It solved the problem of pulling dependency jars.But I have to add one more line under repositories `mavenRepo "http://central.maven.org/maven2/"` and `mavenRepo "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/"`.The problem of invocation still persists, it is not notifying UI.

Comment: It is notifying the, it is printing logs in browser console. open your browser console.

Comment: Or make some change in eventTesting/index page to view effect in page, like..,.  `jQuery("#asd").html("Event should have been already fired..." + data);` line in success of ajax(line 28 of the page) and `<div id="asd"></div>` before body ends.

Comment: No even if I change console log to normal alert message, it was not coming. But I figured out the problem, I will post my finding as the answer. Thanks for your help @user1690588